# Knitr: print text from code block as R markdown

Tags: r, knitr, r-markdown

I have the following R Markdown document:

````
---
title: "Test"
output: html_document
---

```{r cars, echo=FALSE}
myCondition <- TRUE
if(myCondition) {
  print("## Car Summary")
}
summary(cars)
```
````

When I Knit it to HTML, the "Car Summary" header is rendered in "terminal-like" monospaced font as this:

```
## [1] "## Car Summary"
```

But I want it rendered as a header. How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

This should work for you:

````
```{r cars, echo=FALSE, results='asis'}
myCondition <- TRUE
if(myCondition) {
  cat("## Car Summary")
}
```

```{r, echo=FALSE}
summary(cars)
```
````

Note that the option `results = 'asis'` is important to print the header. Also note that `print()` will not work, but `cat()`.