# Create R markdown chunks WITH different chunk options AND markdown headings in a for loop

Tags: r, for-loop, r-markdown, knitr

I would like to automatically generate **R markdown** chunks and headings within a `for` loop in **R** for a `list` of `data.frame`s which varies length depending on input. These are then the input for plot generation. This R markdown document will then be knitted to a `html_document` using the package `knitr`.

I have attempted the solutions from several similar SO questions which can get me close, but is not what I actually need:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/44671368/10771401
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/57034752/10771401

The **problem** is that I have 4 chunks that I'd like to repeat where each chunk has to have *different* chunk options (`fig.width`, `fig.height`) to correctly display the `ggplot2` objects in them. So, I can't simply just supply a single set of options in the code chunk itself).

Here is an example of one of my failed attempts (NOTE: the second code block below also contains a comment indicating the chunk options which is required):

```r
# Chunk data demo
data_list <- list(a=data.frame(), b=data.frame(), c=data.frame())
plot_1 <- list()
plot_2 <- list()

for (i in 1:length(data_list)) {
  data_list[[i]] <- data.frame(x = 1:5, y = 1:5)
  plot_1[[i]] <- ggplot(data_list[[i]], aes(x, y)) + geom_point()
  plot_2[[i]] <- ggplot(data_list[[i]], aes(x, y)) + geom_point()
}
```

````r
#```{r, results='asis'} (Start of R markdown chunk)

# Chunk generation (only 2 chunks are written for brevity)   
for (i in 1:length(data_list)) {
  # Section heading
  cat("\n\n")
  cat("##", names(data_list)[i])

  # Chunk 1 ----
  cat("\n\n")
  cat("### Sub-section 1")
  cat("\n\n")
  cat("**Title 1**")
  cat("\n\n")
  cat('```{r, fig.width=10, fig.height=10}')
  cat("\n\n")
  print(plot_1[[i]])
  cat("\n\n")
  cat('```')
    
  # Chunk 2 ----
  cat("\n\n")
  cat("### Sub-section 2")
  cat("\n\n")
  cat("**Title 2**")
  cat("\n\n")
  cat('```{r, fig.width=10, fig.height=3}') # NOTE: Change in option
  cat("\n\n")
  print(plot_2[[i]])
  cat("\n\n")
  cat('```')
  cat("\n\n")
}
#``` (End of R markdown chunk)
````

*EDIT: Removed the `ggsave()` calls, as not necessary to illustrate the problem which is apparent in the knitted document.*

Comment: Those lines `ggsave` etc. don't appear to be put into the document:  they are being run in the loop, and nothing in the document you are producing includes the files they produce.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your comment, but the plots are created in an earlier chunk in the document. They are also produced in a `for` loop and are appended to a list with each iteration. They are then printed in the chunk as you see above (following the example here: https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/results-asis.html). The `ggsave()` is only there for me to check the output, which works as the files are produced. But as I outlined in the question, the problem is that I can't set different chunk options for multiple chunks. If there is a different approach I'd like to know.

Comment: I must have misunderstood what you are doing.  But since it is incomplete, I can't just try it.  So please simplify it and post a complete, reproducible example.

Comment: @user2554330 thank you for attempting to help. I have modified and added code which can demonstrate my attempt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see what you are trying to do, and I think the approach you are taking won't work.  (But I guess you already knew that!)  Here's why:

When you run the `asis` chunk, you are producing Markdown, not R Markdown.  The `fig.width` and `fig.height` options need to be handled by `knitr` when it is processing `R Markdown`, but that only happens once.  The next stage of processing which handles the Markdown is done by Pandoc, and it doesn't know anything about `fig.width` and `fig.height`.

So what you need to do is to produce a "child document", then get `knitr` to include it in your main document.  Those are described here:  https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/child-document.html .  Basically they are just fragments of R Markdown to include in your main document.  Here's a modification of your document that does this:

````
---
title: "Untitled"
author: "Duncan Murdoch"
date: "2023-02-12"
output: 
  html_document:
    keep_md: true
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

## R Markdown

```{r}
library(ggplot2)
# Create the plots
data_list <- list(a=data.frame(), b=data.frame(), c=data.frame())
plot_1 <- list()
plot_2 <- list()

for (i in 1:length(data_list)) {
  data_list[[i]] <- data.frame(x = 1:5, y = 1:5)
  plot_1[[i]] <- ggplot(data_list[[i]], aes(x, y)) + geom_point()
  plot_2[[i]] <- ggplot(data_list[[i]], aes(x, y)) + geom_point()
}
```

```{r echo = FALSE}
# Create a child document
child <- "child.Rmd"
cat("\n", file = child)

# Save typing file = child, append = TRUE every time
# by making a new function to call cat

cat2 <- function(...) cat(..., file = child, append = TRUE)

for (i in 1:length(data_list)) {
  # Section heading
  cat2("\n\n")
  cat2("##", names(data_list)[i])

  # Chunk 1 ----
  cat2("\n\n")
  cat2("### Sub-section 1")
  cat2("\n\n")
  cat2("**Title 1**")
  cat2("\n\n")
  cat2('```{r fig.width=10, fig.height=10}')
  cat2("\n\n")
  cat2("i = ", i, "\n")
  cat2("print(plot_1[[i]])")
  cat2("\n\n")
  cat2('```')
    
  # Chunk 2 ----
  cat2("\n\n")
  cat2("### Sub-section 2")
  cat2("\n\n")
  cat2("**Title 2**")
  cat2("\n\n")
  cat2("```{r fig.width=10, fig.height=3}")
  cat2("\n\n")
  cat2("print(plot_2[[i]])")
  cat2("\n\n")
  cat2('```')
  cat2("\n\n")
}
```

```{r child="child.Rmd"}
```
````

Comment: Thank you, but this method doesn't fully work as the plots for each iteration of the `for` loop are all the same (from the last iteration) in the knitted document.

Comment: Right, you can't refer to `i` after the loop is done.  You need to add `cat2("i =", i)` before the `cat2("print(plot_1[[i]]")` line.

Comment: Thank you, this was very much appreciated. I added `cat2("i <-",  i)` in its own code chunk above the `# Section heading` comment since the section headings also refer to `i`. The method does leave the `"child.Rmd"` behind, so I wish it wouldn't need to create a document, but manually deleting it is no big deal.

Comment: I think you could have a final chunk in the main document containing `unlink("child.Rmd")` to do the cleanup, or put the file in `tempdir()` for automatic cleanup.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the [`knitr::knit_expand()`](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/knit-expand.html) and pass it to the [`knitr::knit_child()`](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/child-document.html#child-document) function.

**Edit**:

````
---
output: html_document
---


```{r, echo=FALSE, results='asis'}
library(purrr)
library(ggplot2)
data_list <- list(a=data.frame(x = 1:5, y = 1:5), b=data.frame(x = 1:5, y = 1:10),  c=data.frame(x = 1:5, y = 1:15))


data_plots_1 <- map(data_list, ~ggplot(.x, aes(x, y)) + geom_point())
data_plots_2 <- map(data_list, ~ggplot(.x, aes(x, y)) + geom_point(color = "red"))

fig_width <- c(7,5,5)
fig_height <- c(5,3,3)

data_names <- data_list %>% names()
```



```{r results='asis', echo=FALSE}
structure_text <- purrr::pmap_chr(list(data_names, fig_width, fig_height), \(data_names,  fig_width, fig_height) {
  knitr::knit_expand(text = c(
    "## Title Plot 1 dataset {{data_names}}", 
    "",
    "",
    "```{r, fig.width= {{ fig_width }},  fig.height= {{ fig_height }}, echo =FALSE }",
    "data_plots_1${{data_names}} ",
    "```",
    "",
    "## Title Plot 2 dataset {{data_names}}", 
    "",
    "",
    "```{r, fig.width= {{ fig_width }},  fig.height= {{ fig_height }}, echo =FALSE }",
    "data_plots_2${{data_names}} ",
    "```",
    ""
    ))
})
res <- knitr::knit_child(text = structure_text, quiet = TRUE)
cat(res, sep = '\n')
````

[image]

**Old**

````
---
output: html_document
---


```{r, echo=FALSE, results='asis'}
library(purrr)
library(ggplot2)
data_list <- list(a=data.frame(x = 1:5, y = 1:5), b=data.frame(x = 1:5, y = 1:10))
data_names <- data_list %>% names()
fig_width <- c(7,5)
fig_height <- c(5,3)
```



```{r results='asis', echo=FALSE}
structure_text <- purrr::pmap_chr(list(data_names, fig_width, fig_height), \(data_names, fig_width, fig_height) {
  knitr::knit_expand(text = c(
    "## {{ data_names }}", 
    "",
    "",
    "```{r, fig.width= {{ fig_width }},  fig.height= {{ fig_height }}, echo =FALSE }",
    "data_list${{data_names}}  |>",
    "  ggplot(aes(x = x, y = y)) +",
    "  geom_point()",
    "```",
    ""))
})
res <- knitr::knit_child(text = structure_text, quiet = TRUE)
cat(res, sep = '\n')
````

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your help, but implementing this doesn't work: `Error in setwd(opts_knit$get("output.dir")) : character argument expected`. There is a difference in my code to yours: you are constructing the `ggplot` plots in the chunk, whereas I have already created them and am trying to print the objects (it's not feasible for me construct the graphs here as they are complex arrangements built with `cowplot()` and the subplots are included conditionally.

Comment: I made an edit, let me know if it works now

Comment: Thank you for your help. I managed to get this method to work by adding at the beginning of the code chunk containing the `structure_text`: `opts_knit$set(output.dir=getwd())`, as I kept running into an error (see previous comment).