# cat() function printing to console, rather than generating new chunk

Tags: r, r-markdown

I am writing a custom function that sets fonts within RMarkdown reports - the minimal reproducible function is below. I am writing this function as part of a custom package. However, when I use the function in an RMarkdown document, it produces the  `cat()`  output in the console, instead of generating a new chunk with this content. When I copy and paste the output as a new chunk, it works.

````
    fonts_markdown <- function()
    
      cat('\n
    ```{r results=\'asis\', echo=FALSE}
    
    cat("
    <style>
    
          @font-face {
        src: url(\'Clarke-Regular.otf\');
        font-family: \'Clarke-Regular\';
    }
    
    @font-face {
        src: url(\'Clarke-Black.otf\');
        font-family: \'Clarke-Black\';
    }
    
    h1 {
      font-family: \'Clarke-Regular\';
      font-size: 48px;
    }
    
    h2 {
      font-family: \'Clarke-Black\';
      font-size: 32px;
    }
    
    </style>
      ")
    ```\n')
````

EDIT - EXTRA INFO: Ideally, I would be able to call the function in an rmarkdown document like this:

````
    ---
    title: "Markdown Font test"
    author: 
    date: "2023-09-12"
    output: html_document
    ---
    
    ```{r setup, include=FALSE}
    knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
    
    library(CustomeFontLibrary)
    
    ```
    
    ## R Markdown
    
    This is an R Markdown document. Font testing.
    
    ```{r}
    fonts_markdown()
    
    ```
````

How do I go about fixing this?

Thanks!

Comment: It's really a `cat`-within-a-chunk-within-a-`cat`? Oof ... are you intending to call `fonts_markdown()` from a chunk within the "real" rmarkdown document? It might be useful to see this "in action" (to further make this reproducible).

Comment: @r2evans ...yep it is a ```cat``` within a ```cat``` :( The idea is indeed to create a generic ```fonts_markdown()``` function to use within the "real" markdown document. The purpose is to main some consistency with fonts across all markdown reports across the organization - and prevent having to copy and paste css font styling from report to report. I've added in some extra info above. But I am open to other suggestions (that are not cats within cats)!

Comment: I think you can do this with "child documents" - see the discussion in this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75419280/create-r-markdown-chunks-with-different-chunk-options-and-markdown-headings-in-a

Comment: Have you considered setting the template itself? Since you're already having to distribute a package around, why not have the latex/docs template itself handle the fonts natively?

Comment: @r2evans - found another solution! I wrapped the CSS in ```HTML()``` from ```htmltools``` instead. It works!